# Can I access a users' description (bio) directly through Tweepy?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I just started tinkering with Tweepy to see the extent of what's possible, and I'm wondering if I can grab a user's description (the short bio on their profile, under the handle) directly. I know the description can be accessed by using a workaround like this:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)

pastrytweet = api.search('pastries')


for twit in pastrytweet:

    print(twit)
```

This gives us an output that is a list (not in the Python sense) of Status objects, each of which contains a ton of information, eg:

> Status(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x038F6EF8>, _json={'created_at': 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'id': XXXXXXXXXXXX, 'id_str': 'XXXXXXXXXXX', 'text': 'RT @XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXX pastries XXXXXX',  '**description**': 'XXXXXXXXX')

I'm trying to access this "description" parameter seen here at the end directly, but any attempt I make returns a "AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'description'".

So if I wanted, say, to search for a term and grab the bio of a user that published a tweet with that term for some reason, how would I proceed? Or even to search people's bios directly? Is it even possible? I read the Tweepy documentation and I didn't really find an answer.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tweepy-getting-the-description-of-a-user/

Comment: Thanks, it does help but I need to know a specific users' name or ID for it to work, it doesn't seem to work through searches.

Answer (score 0):

Each status object return by api.search has an attribute user and under user you'll find the description. The following code should help:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
pastrytweet = api.search('pastries')

for twit in pastrytweet:
    print(twit.user.description)
```